# Bash: my own exit proc

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to have my own exit function defined with in my bash script file.

Example:

```
$] vi myBash.sh

#!/usr/bash
function myFunc()
{
    echo "Inside myFunc"
}

function exit()
{
    echo "My Own Exit Called"
    exit 0
}

myFunc
exit 0

$] sh myBash.sh
Inside myFunc
My Own Exit Called

$]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a trap for EXIT (0):

```
trap exit_function_name EXIT
```

Or

```
trap 'exit command' EXIT
```

References:

> exit [n]
>
> Cause the shell to exit with a status of n.  If n is omitted, the exit
>   status is that of the last command executed.  A trap on EXIT is
>   executed before the shell terminates.
>
> trap [-lp] [[arg] sigspec ...]
>
> The command arg is to be read and executed when the shell receives
>   signal(s) sigspec.  If arg is absent (and there is a single sigspec)
>   or -, each specified signal is reset to its original disposition (the
>   value it had upon entrance to the shell).  If arg is the null string
>   the signal specified by each sigspec is ignored by the shell and by
>   the commands it invokes.  If arg is not present and -p has been
>   supplied, then the trap commands associated with each sigspec are dis‐
>   played.
>
> If a sigspec is EXIT (0) the command arg is executed on exit from the
>   shell.

As for you code, it can be done like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function exit()
{
    echo "My Own Exit Called"
    # exit 0
}

trap exit EXIT
```

Don't call exit anymore as it would trigger the trap and call the function again.

### Update

When creating a custom function, use `builtin` to call the real `exit`:

```
function exit {
    echo "My Own Exit Called"   
    builtin exit 0  ## I think what you really wanted is builtin exit "$1"
}
```

And here's a suggestion so you could pass your own exit message and exit code:

```
function exit {
    echo "$1"
    builtin exit "$2"
}

exit "My own exit called." 0
```

Comment: But I am trying to register "exit" command for user. So user will give exit command but i need to execute some other function and exit. Is that possible?

Comment: @Ashwin Yes you can use `builtin`. I'll make an update.